# In facebook ios6 not entering in to the if(granted ) loop "Sign in with Facebook"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6

Hi I am working "Sign in with facebook",
My code is below
Here not entering in to the if(granted ) loop.
After i clicked the "ok" in pop up the console is printing like below
2`012-11-28 15:47:08.558 Tattoo Later[2748:1d34b] type:com.apple.facebook
identifier: B962F897-6BAE-4769-8C04-B1B3D2C872A2
accountDescription: Facebook
username: example@yahoo.co.in
objectID: x-coredata://EBF41CAD-7388-45E0-8621-3958C7A67491/Account/p1
enabledDataclasses: {(
    "com.apple.Dataclass.Contacts",
    "com.apple.Dataclass.Calendars"
)}
enableAndSyncableDataclasses: {(
)}
properties: {
    fullname = "Example";
    uid = 100001462475956;
}
parentAccount: (null)
owningBundleID:(null)`

My Code when we click "Sign in with Facebook":

```
-(IBAction)loginWithFacebookClicked:(id)sender
{
 ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
NSArray * permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email",@"user_location", nil];
        NSDictionary * dict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"238864112907671",ACFacebookAppIdKey,permissions,ACFacebookPermissionsKey,ACFacebookAudienceEveryone,ACFacebookAudienceKey, nil];
[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:dict completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
            if(granted ) {
                NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
if ([accountsArray count] > 0) {
ACAccount *fbAccount = [accountsArray objectAtIndex:0];
                    NSLog(@"%@",fbAccount);
}
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }];
}
```

Initially i got some errors like

The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: The proxied app cannot request publish permissions without having being installed previously.

Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: invalid app id" UserInfo=0xa29f520 {NSLocalizedDescription=The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: invalid app id}

Later i solved by searching but i did not get solution for this

Please guide me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is very simple! The completion block is called on arbitrary thread LATER. So if you going step by step it actually exits your method and continue work on main thread and later when you get response it enters either if or else section. Your log is actually proving that you've entered if section (it logs account). If you place a break point in if section you'll notice this behavior. So your code is ok.

Comment: Your are welcome, I've spent hours on integrating Social fmw ))

Comment: ok.. How to parse the data , i mean i want to get the email and name from that @Stas

Comment: I can give you some advice though I can't do the work for you :)

Comment: Post a question like "how to parse a NSData *responseData response from FB" And I (or anybody else) will try to answer